# shell script for copying log files into a single compressed file

Tags: linux, shell, ash

We have a folder in our embedded board "statuslogs", this folder contains logs which are of the format : daily_status_date_time.log.

We need to get all the files of a particular year into a single file, for fetching from the server.

We did the following in our script

```
gzip -c statuslogs/daily_status_2017*.log > status_2017.gz
gzip -c statuslogs/daily_status_2018*.log > status_2018.gz
gzip -c statuslogs/daily_status_2019*.log > status_2019.gz
gzip -c statuslogs/daily_status_2020*.log > status_2020.gz
gzip -c statuslogs/daily_status_2021*.log > status_2021.gz
```

The problem with this logic is that it will still create status_*.gz file for the years 2019,2020,2021.

I tried writing the following logic

`if [ - f statuslogs/daily_status_2017*.log ]` but it fails due to regex may be. And I am not using bash, the interpreter is ash.

Can you please help me to optimize the script

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error. It's `-f`, not `- f`. Example:

```
if [ -f statuslogs/daily_status_2017*.log ]; then
    gzip -c statuslogs/daily_status_2017*.log > status_2017.gz
fi
```

However, with this you will probably run into a "too many arguments" error, which will happen if you have more than one matching file. So this would work better:

```
if find statuslogs/daily_status_2017*.log -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0|head -n1; then 
    gzip -c statuslogs/daily_status_2017*.log > status_2017.gz
fi
```

It would be better to instead stop the loop when you reach the current year. For example,

```
for year in $(seq 2017 $(date +%Y)); do
```

Comment: When I do echo $year i am getting {2017..2018}

Comment: Sorry - I fixed the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Gzip only works on single files. If you want the separate files you need to do one of the following:

Combine the files using tar:

```
tar cf status_2017.tar.gz statuslogs/daily_status_2017*.log
```

OR use zip which supports multiple files directly

```
zip status_2017.zip statuslogs/daily_status_2017*.log
```

Now, if the problem is just that you want one archive for every year, but only for the years for which files exist, you can handle all the years using a `for` loop:

```
for year in `ls statuslogs/daily_status_* | cut -d _ -f 3 | sort | uniq`; do 
    tar cf status_$year.tar.gz statuslogs/daily_status_$year*.log; 
done
```

If your shell doesn't support that format of calling, you can try this instead

```
ls statuslogs/daily_status_* | cut -d _ -f 3 | sort | uniq > years
cat years | while read year; do
    tar cf status_$year.tar.gz statuslogs/daily_status_$year*.log; 
done
```

If you just want one file for all the logs, you can just forget about the year part completely

```
tar cf statuslogs.tar.gz statuslogs/daily_status*.log
```

Comment: But gzip is working for me on multiple files and it is creating a single file containing all the logs of that year... The above for loop will still continue for all the years irrespective of the current year..

Comment: No.. I need one file for each year.. zip command is not there in my embedded board. tar command output size is greater than gzip, so I have to choose gzip

Comment: The way you do it in your command will end up concatenating all the files into one gz. Using tar you will be able to get the files off the server as they were.

Comment: @md.jamal My most recent edit finds files which exist forst and produces an archive for every year for which logs exist.

Comment: Noted.. But the below for loop is simple solution which is working for me.. Thanks for your time and support